# C# using simpleJSON to get a random object

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, simplejson

I want to get a random object inside BodyPresets in the json below.
I'm using it because it is simple to understand and it was successful in fetching a string for me.

```
{
    "BodyPresets":[
    {  
       "name":"bodypreset1",
       "height": {"x":0.3, "y":0.5},
       "upper_arms": {"x":0.3, "y":0.5},
       "lower_arms": {"x":0.3, "y":0.5}
    },
    {  
       "name":"bodypreset2",
       "height": {"x":0.5, "y":0.7},
       "upper_arms": {"x":0.5, "y":0.7},
       "lower_arms": {"x":0.5, "y":0.7}
    },
    {  
       "name":"bodypreset3",
       "height": {"x":0.7, "y":0.9},
       "upper_arms": {"x":0.7, "y":0.9},
       "lower_arms": {"x":0.7, "y":0.9}
    }
    ]
}
```

In the C# code below i tried but only got a CS0121 error:

```
using SimpleJSON;

    void RandomiseCharBody()
    {
        var dllPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string configFilename = "Randomizer.json";
        var configPath = Path.Combine(dllPath, configFilename);
        
        //// from https://answers.unity.com/questions/1473952/how-to-write-and-read-json-in-unity.html  
        //// https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(configPath); 
        JSONNode data = JSON.Parse(jsonString);
        JSONNode BodyPresets = data["BodyPresets"];
        
        //attempt at gettting a random preset from the list
        var randompreset = BodyPresets[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, BodyPresets.Count)];
        JSONNode preset = BodyPresets[randompreset];

        float min1 = preset["height"]["x"];
        float min2 = preset["upper_arms"]["x"];
        float min3 = preset["lower_arms"]["x"];
        
        float max1 = preset["height"]["y"];
        float max2 = preset["upper_arms"]["y"];
        float max3 = preset["lower_arms"]["y"];
        
        // applies the values
        shapeValueBody[0] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min1, max1);
        shapeValueBody[1] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min2, max2);
        shapeValueBody[2] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min3, max3);
    }
```

but how can this be done?

Comment: Can you post the full text of the error?

Comment: @Abion47 Error CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'JSONNode.this[int]' and 'JSONNode.this[string]' Randomizer

Comment: In which line are you getting this error?

Comment: @OnionFan at   JSONNode preset = BodyPresets[randompreset];

Comment: But in this line - var randompreset = BodyPresets[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, BodyPresets.Count)]; -  you already get the random preset, no?

And in this line you are trying to get preset using the object - JSONNode preset = BodyPresets[randompreset];, strange behavior

Comment: @OnionFan You're right. That wasn't needed and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't needed:

```
JSONNode preset = BodyPresets[randompreset];
```

Because

```
var randompreset = BodyPresets[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, BodyPresets.Count)];
```

already gets a random object.

Thanks to @OnionFan